# Android application slowing down after some time, causing a lot of GC_CONCURRENT

Tags: android, memory-management, garbage-collection

I am writing a chat application based on IRC. The app runs well in the beginning but as we start using it and there starts to be a lot of messages incoming, the app significantly slows down and finally an ANR pops out. This happens on the lobby (the group chat) view where the user can see the list of online users, the list of private messages etc. I have tried everything, like eclipse memory analyzer, DDMS CPU profiling. I cannot find the actual issue. Its driving me crazy. I dont know what the issue is. I am using a Service that will send listen for a message and send broadcast message when it receives a message.On the service, I am starting a new thread that has a socket opened and a continuous loop. Once the app starts lagging I get a lot of GC_CONCURRENT messages:

```
01-30 20:28:39.240: D/dalvikvm(14593): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1321K, 33% free 11755K/17415K, paused 110ms+41ms, total 292ms
01-30 20:28:39.240: D/dalvikvm(14593): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 182ms
01-30 20:28:48.780: D/dalvikvm(14593): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1784K, 33% free 11813K/17415K, paused 116ms+25ms, total 243ms
01-30 20:28:48.780: D/dalvikvm(14593): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 128ms
01-30 20:28:50.420: D/dalvikvm(14593): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1893K, 33% free 11763K/17415K, paused 111ms+11ms, total 169ms
01-30 20:28:50.420: D/dalvikvm(14593): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 59ms
```

I dont know what my problem is. I am trying to figure it out since last 5 days and no progress.

Here is my code for the Service:

```
public class ChatService extends Service{
       public static final String BROADCAST_ACTION =
                "com.webbisswift.NepalMessenger.Broadcast";
       public static final String BROADCAST_CHANMSG=
               "com.webbisswift.NepalMessenger.BroadcastChannelMessage";
       public static final String BROADCAST_PMMSG=
               "com.webbisswift.NepalMessenger.BroadcastPrivateMessage";
       public static final String BROADCAST_USERJOIN=
               "com.webbisswift.NepalMessenger.BroadcastUserJoin";
       public static final String BROADCAST_USERLEAVE=
               "com.webbisswift.NepalMessenger.BroadcastUserLeave";
       public static final String BROADCAST_USERLISTARRIVE=
               "com.webbisswift.NepalMessenger.BroadcastUserListArrive";
       public static final String BROADCAST_ALERT=
               "com.webbisswift.NepalMessenger.BroadcastAlert";
       public static final String BROADCAST_KICKED=
               "com.webbisswift.NepalMessenger.BroadcastUserKicked";
       public static final String BROADCAST_NICK_CHANGED=
               "com.webbisswift.NepalMessenger.BroadcastNickChanged";
       public static final String CACHE_HEAD="com.webbisswift.NepalMessenger.PMCache.";
       public static final int MASTER_NOTIF=111;
       private IRCHandler irc;
       private String quitMsg="Download Chat Chautari for Android.";
       private boolean bound;
       private Context mContext=this;
       public ArrayList<String> pmList=new ArrayList<String>();
       private RoomDatabase room_db;
       private PMDatabase pm_db;
    public String getCurNick(){
        if(irc!=null)
        return irc.nick;
        else{
            Log.d("IRC","IRC NULL");
            return null;
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<String>  getUsers(){
        return irc.userMap;
    }
    public String getCurChannel(){
        return irc.channel;
    }

    public void putToPMList(String nick){
        if(!pmList.contains(nick))
            pmList.add(nick);
    }

    private void showPMNotification(Message message){
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle("PM From: "+message.getFrom())
        .setContentText(message.getPayload());
        Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        builder.setSound(soundUri);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PMActivity.class);
        Log.d("NOTIF_FROM",message.getFrom());
        intent.putExtra("PEER", message.getFrom());
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        builder.setContentIntent(pIntent);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // mId allows you to update the notification later on.

        mNotificationManager.notify(110,builder.build());
    }





    public void disconnectIRC(){
        if(irc!=null)
            irc.closeConnection();
    }



    private Notification getMasterNotification(String channel,String nick){
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle(getText(R.string.app_name))
        .setContentText("Connecting to "+channel+" as "+nick);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, RoomActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
        builder.setContentIntent(pIntent);
        Notification notif=builder.build();
        notif.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT | Notification.FLAG_FOREGROUND_SERVICE | Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
        return notif;
    }

    private void setMasterNotification(String message){
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle(getText(R.string.app_name))
        .setContentText(message);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, RoomActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
        builder.setContentIntent(pIntent);
        Notification notif=builder.build();
        notif.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT | Notification.FLAG_FOREGROUND_SERVICE | Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            // mId allows you to update the notification later on.

            mNotificationManager.notify(MASTER_NOTIF,builder.build());
    }




        public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
            ChatService getService() {
                return ChatService.this;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
             bound = true;
            return mBinder;
        }
        private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

         public boolean send(Message message){
             if(irc.sendMessage(message)){
                 if(message.getTo().contentEquals(getCurChannel())){
                     //add sent msg to roomdb
                     room_db.addMessage(message);
                 }else{
                     pm_db.addMessage(message.getFrom()+": "+message.getPayload(), message.getTo());
                 }
                 return true;
             }
             else { 
             return false; 
             }
         }

         public boolean sendCommand(String command){
             return irc.sendCommand(command);
         }

         public void setQuitMsg(String msg){
             this.quitMsg=msg;
         }

         public void changeNick(String nick){
             irc.changeNick(nick);
         }

         public void registerNick(String pass,String email){
             irc.registerNick(pass, email);
         }
         public boolean quit(){
            return irc.quit(quitMsg);

         }


         @Override
         public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
             bound = false;
             return true; // ensures onRebind is called
         }

         @Override
         public void onRebind(Intent intent) {
             bound = true;
         }

         public void reJoin(){
            if( irc.join())
                setMasterNotification("Connected to "+irc.channel);

         }
         @Override
          public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
              //now start communication thread
                final String nick=intent.getStringExtra("NICK");
                final String channel=intent.getStringExtra("CHANNEL");
                final String password=intent.getStringExtra("PASSWORD");
                room_db=new RoomDatabase(mContext);
                pm_db=new PMDatabase(mContext);
                pm_db.open();
                room_db.open();
                //check if internet is there or not         
                if(!isOnline()){
                        //failure
                        Log.d("SERVICE","LOGIN FAIL");
                        sendLoginResponse(IRCHandler.LOGIN_FAIL);
                        setMasterNotification("No internet connection.");
                }
                setMasterNotification("Connecting..");
                Thread t=new Thread(new Runnable(){

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            irc=new IRCHandler("irc.chatsansar.com",nick,channel,6667);
                            int response=irc.login(password);
                            Log.d("SERVICE","LOGIN CALLED");
                            if(response==IRCHandler.LOGIN_SUCCESS){
                                //login successful reply this msg to the GUI
                                Log.d("SERVICE","LOGIN SUCCESS");
                                sendLoginResponse(IRCHandler.LOGIN_SUCCESS);
                                setMasterNotification("Connected, joining channel..");
                                if(irc.join()){
                                    sendJoinResponse(IRCHandler.JOIN_SUCCESS);
                                    //we need to use some listeners
                                    setMasterNotification("Joined channel: "+channel);
                                    irc.setChannelListener(new ChannelListener(){

                                        @Override
                                        public void onNewMessage(Message message) {
                                            // When a new message comes, send a message broadcast

                                            if(bound)
                                              sendLastMessage(message);
                                             room_db.addMessage(message);
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onAlert(String alert) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                            sendAlert(alert);

                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onUserLeave(String nick,String message) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                            sendLeaveMessage(nick,message);
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onUserJoin(String user) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                            sendJoinMessage(user);
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onUserListArrive() {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                            sendULArrive();
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onKicked(String msg) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                            setMasterNotification("Kicked from channel.");
                                            sendKickedNotice(msg);
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onNickChanged() {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                             resetNick();
                                        }});


                                    irc.setPMListener(new PMListener(){

                                        @Override
                                        public void onNewMessage(Message message) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                            if(!pmList.contains(message.getFrom()))
                                                 pmList.add(message.getFrom());
                                            if(bound){
                                              sendPM(message);
                                            }else{
                                                showPMNotification(message);
                                            }
                                            pm_db.addMessage(message.getFrom()+": "+message.getPayload(),message.getFrom());
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onKicked(String msg) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                            sendKickedNotice(msg);
                                        }

                                    });


                               irc.readServer();


                                }
                                else {
                                    sendJoinResponse(IRCHandler.JOIN_SUCCESS);
                                    irc.closeConnection();
                                }
                            }else if(response==IRCHandler.NICK_TAKEN){
                                //nick already taken.
                                Log.d("SERVICE","NICK TAKEN");
                                sendLoginResponse(IRCHandler.NICK_TAKEN);
                            }else if(response==IRCHandler.INVALID_NICK){
                                //nick already taken.
                                Log.d("SERVICE","INVALID NICK");
                                sendLoginResponse(IRCHandler.INVALID_NICK);
                            }else{
                                //failure
                                Log.d("SERVICE","LOGIN FAIL");
                                sendLoginResponse(IRCHandler.LOGIN_FAIL);
                            }

                            room_db.close();
                            pm_db.close();
                            irc.closeConnection();

                        }catch(Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            room_db.close();
                            pm_db.close();
                            Log.d("SERVICE","IRC DISCONNECTED");
                            sendLoginResponse(IRCHandler.LOGIN_FAIL);
                            setMasterNotification("Disconnected from server.");
                            stopSelf();
                        }
                    }

                });


                t.start();
                startForeground(MASTER_NOTIF, getMasterNotification(channel,nick));
            return Service.START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
          }


    protected void sendLeaveMessage(String nick, String message) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent localIntent=new Intent(ChatService.BROADCAST_USERLEAVE);
        localIntent.putExtra("NICK",nick);
        localIntent.putExtra("MESSAGE", message);
        sendBroadcast(localIntent);
    }

    private void sendJoinResponse(int joinSuccess) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent localIntent =
                new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);
        localIntent.putExtra("JOIN",joinSuccess);
        sendBroadcast(localIntent);
    }

    private void sendLoginResponse(int response){
    Intent localIntent =
            new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);
    localIntent.putExtra("LOGIN",response);
    sendBroadcast(localIntent);
    }

    private void sendLastMessage(Message msg){
        Intent localIntent=new Intent(ChatService.BROADCAST_CHANMSG);
        localIntent.putExtra("MESSAGE", msg.getPayload());
        localIntent.putExtra("FROM", msg.getFrom());
        localIntent.putExtra("MESSAGE", msg.getPayload());
        sendBroadcast(localIntent);
        }

    private void sendJoinMessage(String user){
        Intent localIntent=new Intent(ChatService.BROADCAST_USERJOIN);
        localIntent.putExtra("NICK",user);
        sendBroadcast(localIntent);
        }

    private void sendULArrive(){
        Intent localIntent=new Intent(ChatService.BROADCAST_USERLISTARRIVE);
        sendBroadcast(localIntent);
        }


    private void sendPM(Message msg){
        Intent localIntent=new Intent(ChatService.BROADCAST_PMMSG);
        localIntent.putExtra("MESSAGE", msg.getPayload());
        localIntent.putExtra("FROM", msg.getFrom());
        sendBroadcast(localIntent);
    }

    private void sendAlert(String alert){
        Intent localIntent=new Intent(ChatService.BROADCAST_ALERT);
        localIntent.putExtra("MESSAGE", alert);
        sendBroadcast(localIntent);
    }

    private void sendKickedNotice(String msg){
        Intent localIntent=new Intent(ChatService.BROADCAST_KICKED);
        localIntent.putExtra("MESSAGE",msg );
        sendBroadcast(localIntent);
    }

    private void resetNick(){
        Intent localIntent=new Intent(ChatService.BROADCAST_NICK_CHANGED);
        sendBroadcast(localIntent);
    }

    public boolean hasIRC() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(irc==null)
         return false;
        else return true;
    }

    private boolean isOnline() {
        ConnectivityManager cm =
            (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void delDB() {
        Log.d("DATABASE","CLEARED");
         room_db.drop();
         pm_db.drop();
    }
}
```

Comment: You're are allocating and freeing too many objects too often. Also, how are you "looping" in your worker thread?

Comment: I wrote a IRCHandler class that has a method, readServer(), that has a long running while loop. If a new message comes, it is processed and sent to the service via Java Interfaces. The Service will then update the Activities by sending a Broadcast message. And about the allocating and freeing too many objects, isnt it supposed to free up the memory and make the app perform better?

Comment: And also Gil, isn't the GC_CONCURRENT running asynchronously? So why is it interfering with my UI thread? The block times are criminal to app, as it slows down the app very badly as any delay >100ms will be considered as poor performance.

Comment: Yes it runs asynchronously since Gingerbread. You're opening two databases on the UI thread but this is not your problem as you have a slow down after a while. For sure there is some garbage in all those notifications, but I suspect in `readServer()` you do something like `while(true) {...}` without a waiting mechanism. What phone are you testing on? Does it have more than two cores?

Comment: PS: a call to the GC takes roughly 300ms

Comment: First of all Gil, thank you so much for clearing some of my misconceptions.I am using while((line=reader.readLine)!=null) as the condition for loop).Its not the issue in my opinion because the private message works fine. Its only on the lobby or group chat activity the slowing down occurs.

 Leaving everything else, is the way of my coding the optimal way for such type of application? Should I use any other approach? Ill be glad for any response from your side.

Comment: I can't say for sure whether your programming style is optimal, especially from the performance point of view. To optimise a bit you could consider [local broadcasts](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html).

Also [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk) IO talk by Patrik Dubroy about memory management will be helpful

Comment: Well, thank you Gil, I will try with LocalBroadcasts and I have already watched that video as I said I have tried Memory Analyzer to find a leak. I will try to rewrite the code with local broadcasts and less no of objects being created if I can.